# DDD Specification pattern - where do they belong?

Tags: domain-driven-design, specification-pattern

I have an array of Users and I need to know if the array contains only one User and if so, is that User a super user. For this, I think a Specification (isSatisifedBy) is perfect for this, however, where in my application should I save these files? in the bounded context under a Specification folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/xref/se/citerus/dddsample/domain/model/cargo/RouteSpecification.html) example made by Eric Evans in his famous book on DDD.

A specification is part of the domain model, so there should live in the same package of the model, so of course in the same bounded context.
In this example, `Cargo` is the model and `RouteSpecification` is one of its specification.

Comment: Woww! Great and convenient example.